# How to increment an instance with setter?

Tags: java, getter-setter

I have a little problem in a simple class.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class fileTest {

    private static Random rand = new Random();;
    private int randOne = rand.nextInt(10);
    private String strOne = String.format("%02d", this.randOne);

    public int getRandOne() {
        return randOne;
    }

    public void setRandOne(int randOne) {
        this.randOne = randOne +1;
    }

    public String getStrOne() {
        return strOne;
    }

}
```

My "launcher"

```
public class launch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        fileTest fileA = new fileTest();
        System.out.println(fileA.getStrOne());

        //FunctionDoMyStuff...

        fileA.setRandOne(fileA.getRandOne());

        System.out.println(fileA.getRandOne());
        //RandOne is increment

        System.out.println(fileA.getStrOne());
        //StrOne is not

    }
}
```

My idea is to create a random number and transform it into a string.
After finishing my stuff, I need to increment my string.

But the result after the setter is the same as in the beginning. I think I don't understand everything about a getter/setter.

Can anyone help me to understand my mistake?

Comment: `private String strOne = String.format("%02d", this.randOne);` this is **not tied**  to `this.randOne` as a variable. Instead, it is evaluated **once**, when creating the instance (when calling the constructor). And then it uses the current value of `randOne`. It is never recomputed.

Answer (score 4):

This happens once at the time that your instance is created:

```
private String strOne = String.format("%02d", this.randOne);
```

It isn't automatically run again after you change `randOne`. The solution is to remove the `strOne` field altogether and construct the String inside the getter:

```
public String getStrOne() {
    return String.format("%02d", this.randOne);
}
```

You don't need to store a dynamically derived value.

---

The behaviour of your method `setRandOne` doesn't match what people might reasonably expect a `set` method to do. A method that does what yours does could be described as `setRandOneToOneHigherThan(int value)`. Or you could call it `incrementRandOne()` but then the body needs to do `this.randOne = this.randOne + 1;` (or `this.randOne++;`). Or you could make it a normal setter and do the incrementing while you call the method: `fileA.setRandOne(fileA.getRandOne() + 1);`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I heard that you have to avoid putting formulas in a getter. I am wrong?

Comment: @K.Asuus It's fine to have a formula in a getter (but it would be a read-only property, it would be strange to have a setter too for that property). The reason for having getters and setters rather than accessing the field directly, is so that you can add logic to them (and possibly override the methods in subclasses). So it shouldn't be a problem to put logic in it - but don't do things that people wouldn't expect from a method looking at its name.

Comment: Oh you're rigth @AndyTurner. In the future it's better that avoid actions like that on a setter. incrementRandOne() seems more revelant in my case.